# Problems when scaling and translating image on canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, transformation

At work we built a complex application using C#/WPF and the MVVM pattern. In the application we have a canvas. On that canvas we display an image at the center of the canvas. We want to be able to scale and translate the image. We can specify a scale factor to scale all elements on the canvas. To apply transformations to the image we bound a TransformGroup to the RenderTransform property of the image in XAML. The TransformGroup is built in the view model by first adding the ScaleTransform followed by the TranslateTransform.

The transformations are specified that way:

```cs
// View model
// Global fileds
private ScaleTransform scaleTransform = new ScaleTransform(1, 1);
private TranslateTransform translateTransform = new TranslateTransform(0, 0);
private Vector totalShift = new Vector(0, 0);

...

public void ApplyTransformations() {
    scaleTransform.ScaleX = scaleFactor;
    scaleTransform.ScaleY = scaleFactor;

    translateTransform.X = canvasCenter.X - imageWidth / 2;
    translateTransform.Y = canvasCenter.Y - imageHeight / 2;
}
```

Now we are able to scale the image properly when changing the scale factor.

To enable translation of the image we put the image into a Thumb. The thumb provides a DragDelta event that gives us the shift in x and y direction. This shift is added to totalShift each time we drag the thumb. The following method is part of the view model and is called by the DragDelta event handler in the code behind of the view.

```cs
public void addShift(double horizontal, double vertical) {
    totalShift.X += horizontal;
    totalShift.Y += vertical;
}
```

ApplyTransformations() is modified like this:

```cs
private double prevScaleFactor = 0;

public void ApplyTransformations() {
    double oldCenterX = scaleTransform.CenterX;
    double oldCenterY = scaleTransform.CenterY;

    scaleTransform.CenterX = -totalShift.X;
    scaleTransform.CenterY = -totalShift.Y;

    translateTransform.X = (canvasCenter.X - imageWidth / 2) + (scaleTransform.CenterX - oldCenterX) * prevScaleFactor;
    translateTransform.Y = (canvasCenter.Y - imageHeight / 2) + (scaleTransform.CenterY - oldCenterY) * prevScaleFactor;

    scaleTransform.ScaleX = scaleFactor;
    scaleTransform.ScaleY = scaleFactor;

    prevScaleFactor = scaleFactor;
}
```

The problem:
Let's say scaleFactor is 1.5 and we dragged the image 100 px in x direction. When we execute ApplyTransformation() the image is not shifted 100 px in x direction but only 100 / 1.5 = 66.67 px. This means that the shift is scaled before it is applied.

How can we achieve this? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**
The TransformGroup is built that way:

```cs
private TransformGroup _transform = new TransformGroup();
public TransformGroup Transform {
    get {
        _transformGroup.Children.Clear();
        _transformGroup.Children.Add(scaleTransform);
        _transformGroup.Children.Add(translateTransform);
    }
}
```

If i do it this way the problem described above occures.

**Edit 2**

I've created a [MCVE](https://1drv.ms/f/s!AreFTln1GEWNa4p4xYKaVIDKwJU), so you can run it and see the problem. Change the scale factor to a value not equal to 1.0. Then drag the black canvas with your mouse away from the red point (center point) and change the scale factor again. Now the black canvas seems to jump a bit.

Comment: Change the order of the children of the TransformGroup?

Comment: Did you also fix the CenterX and CenterY of the ScaleTransform? You might perhaps better set the Image's RenderTansformOrigin.

Comment: I set the RenderTransformOrigin to the negative totalShift instead of setting it to CenterX and CenterY of the scale transform, but it did not work too.

Comment: RenderTransformOrigin is in relative coordinates, i.e. `(0.5, 0.5)` is the center of an element. Please take a look at the online documentation.

Comment: I can't use RenderTransformOrigin because the center point can move too. I've added a minimal working example so may be you can try it to see the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are applying your transformations in the wrong order. First you are translating, then you are scaling. You should instead try applying your scale change to your image, followed by any rotation to your image (in this example, you aren't using any), followed by any translations.

Check out this MSDN article for more information on order of transformations: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eews39w7(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I updated my post. If i switch the order of the children the image doesn't scale properly any more, even though first scaling then translating seems to be correct.

Comment: Ensure that your transforms are setup correctly by following @Clemens advice above.